# Why initialization of Xgboost DMatrix reducec features number?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas, xgboost

I am trying to understand following case:

1. when I create new `xgbost` DMatrix

   `xgX = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=Y, missing=np.nan)`
2. based on input data **X**  with 64 features
   [image]
3. I got the new DMatrix with 55 features
   [image]

What the magic is doing here? Any advise would be great!

Comment: Without looking at the code it is difficult to tell what is happening. Can you share your X and Y shape.